# Add custom spinner image for the Devextreme Datagrid header filter

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme

There is a loadPanel configuration for the datagrid control by devextreme.

https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/loadPanel/

However, I want the same configurability for the spinner inside the header filter of the columns in the data grid for consistency.

I need to use a custom gif and remove the default panel and loading text thats been shown
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't built-in functionality you mentioned. Anyway, you can customize it using CSS.

In this case you have to inspect html markup and change styles that you need.

In this [sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/evEXwp) I've changed the following styles to customize loading indicator in header filter:

```
/* hide 'Loading...' message */
.dx-header-filter-menu .dx-scrollview-scrollbottom-text {
    display: none;
}

/* hide default loading icon */
.dx-header-filter-menu .dx-loadindicator-icon .dx-loadindicator-segment {
    display: none;
}

/* use custom loading icon */
.dx-header-filter-menu .dx-loadindicator-icon {
    background: url('https://preloaders.net/preloaders/3/Chasing%20arrows.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

And yes, I use jQuery approach here. But it doesn't make sense, cause in Angular2 app you have to override the same styles.

Comment: Worked like a charm.Thank you very much. I had to remove dx-header-filter-menu as the hierarchy was a bit different. Instead used "/deep/ .dx-loadindicator-icon". Also, tried to change the size for the icon to a bigger number but couldn't. Anything for that?

Comment: I think it should be `/deep/ .dx-loadindicator { width: 64px; height: 64px; }`